# How do I get Zend Di to use setter injection with RuntimeDefinition

Tags: zend-framework2

I have class with some setters and I'd like setter injection to be used, but with a RuntimeDefinition it's just not triggering. I initially thought it might not be possible, but then I upgraded to Zend 2.1.0 and started getting an error with my Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter that was getting injected in some other classes because a new setProfiler() method was introduced and it's trying to do setter injection on it (while using the default RuntimeDefinition). I looked at the code for Adapter and the only difference I saw between that code and mine is that the setProfiler() method had some doc comments with @param in it, so I thought maybe reflection uses this. I added some to my code and it also doesn't work. Clearly I'm missing something. Even when I compile to a DI definition file, I can see that Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter has an entry like this under its definition:

```
'methods' => 
array (
  '__construct' => true,
  'setProfiler' => true,
)
```

Whereas my definition looks like this:

```
'methods' => 
array (
  'setMyValue' => false,
)
```

How do I get Di to correctly identify my setter functions so they get used to inject the necessary values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much looking into the internals of the [`CompilerDefinition`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/release-2.1.1/library/Zend/Di/Definition/CompilerDefinition.php) class, I've figured it out.

The reason the setter gets called in the case of  Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter is because of the `Profiler\ProfilerAwareInterface`.

It appears that if your class implements an interface and there's a setter in that interface, then the setter will get called. It's also important that the implemented interface name be something that [matches the regex `/\w*Aware\w*/`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/release-2.1.1/library/Zend/Di/Definition/IntrospectionStrategy.php#L31-L34).

You can see an example of this logic in [Ralphschindler's `Zend\Di` Examples](https://github.com/ralphschindler/Zend_DI-Examples/blob/master/example-02.php).